# typeorm set fk for column without primary key

Tags: typescript, typeorm

Hello I'm trying to set a foreign key to a column that is not a primary key in typeorm, but I'm getting errors

i have employee and departament

I have a column in the department manager id that must reference the column register in the employee table

employee entity:

```
@Entity({ name: 'employees' })
export class Employee extends SharedProp {
  constructor(
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string,
  ) {
    super();
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column({ name: 'matricula', nullable: false })
  matricula: string;

  @Column({ name: 'first_name', nullable: false })
  firstName: string;

  @Column({ name: 'last_name', nullable: false })
  lastName: string;

  @Column({ type: 'string', name: 'user_id', nullable: true })
  user_id: string;

  @Column()
  departament_id: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Departament, (departament: Departament) => departament.employees)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'departament_id' })
  departament: Departament;

  @OneToOne(() => User)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'user_id' })
  user: User;
}
```

Departament Entity:

```
@Entity({ name: 'departaments' })
export class Departament {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column()
  departament_name: string;

  @Column({ type: 'string', name: 'manager_id', nullable: true })
  manager_id: string | null;

  @OneToOne(() => Employee, employee => employee.departament, {
    nullable: true,
  })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'manager_id', referencedColumnName: 'matricula' })
  manager: Employee;

  @OneToMany(() => Employee, (employee: Employee) => employee.departament)
  employees: Array<Employee>;

  @CreateDateColumn({ name: 'created_at' })
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn({ name: 'updated_at' })
  UpdatedAt: Date;
}
```

I tried to generate a migration that resulted in this:

```
export class refactor1597449093253 implements MigrationInterface {
    name = 'refactor1597449093253'

    public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "departaments" DROP CONSTRAINT "FK_65bfca70b0ffbf5351061f2ea64"`);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "departaments" DROP CONSTRAINT "UQ_65bfca70b0ffbf5351061f2ea64"`);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "departaments" DROP COLUMN "manager_id"`);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "departaments" ADD "manager_id" character varying`);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "departaments" ADD CONSTRAINT "UQ_65bfca70b0ffbf5351061f2ea64" UNIQUE ("manager_id")`);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "departaments" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_65bfca70b0ffbf5351061f2ea64" FOREIGN KEY ("manager_id") REFERENCES "employees"("matricula") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION`);
    }

    public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "departaments" DROP CONSTRAINT "FK_65bfca70b0ffbf5351061f2ea64"`);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "departaments" DROP CONSTRAINT "UQ_65bfca70b0ffbf5351061f2ea64"`);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "departaments" DROP COLUMN "manager_id"`);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "departaments" ADD "manager_id" uuid`);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "departaments" ADD CONSTRAINT "UQ_65bfca70b0ffbf5351061f2ea64" UNIQUE ("manager_id")`);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "departaments" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_65bfca70b0ffbf5351061f2ea64" FOREIGN KEY ("manager_id") REFERENCES "employees"("id") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION`);
    }

}
```

but i got this error when run migration:

> query failed: ALTER TABLE "departaments" ADD CONSTRAINT
> "FK_65bfca70b0ffbf5351061f2ea64" FOREIGN KEY ("manager_id") REFERENCES
> "employees"("matricula") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION

> error: error: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for
> referenced table "employee

Comment: matricula is not constrained to be unique